# Compiling superopt on windows

Tags: makefile, compilation

I'm triing to compile the superoptimizer on windows. (https://github.com/bonzini/superopt)
Unfortunatly my knowledge of make is very limited. I tried:

```
make CPU=-D386 superopt
```

Which gives me the error:

```
cc     superopt.c   -o superopt
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc superopt.c -o superopt, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [superopt] Fehler 2
```

After setting the compiler to gcc manually with:

```
make CPU=-D386 superopt CC=gcc
```

I get the following error:

```
gcc     superopt.c   -o superopt
In file included from superopt.c:27:0:
superopt.h:104:2: error: #error You have to choose target CPU type (--with-arch).
 #error You have to choose target CPU type (--with-arch).
  ^
In file included from superopt.h:130:0,
                 from superopt.c:27:
longlong.h:1465:14: error: unknown type name 'UQItype'
 extern const UQItype __clz_tab[];
              ^
superopt.c:32:21: fatal error: version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [superopt] Fehler 1
```

It seems it does't properly selects i386.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That](https://github.com/bonzini/superopt) is not the source code of
GNU `superopt`. It is the source code of someone's project
to patch GNU `superopt`, last updated 2008, and seemingly
abandoned a hard-hat area.

[This](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/superopt/) is the source code of
GNU `superopt`. Extract the tarball and build as you have attempted
with:

```
make CC=gcc CPU=-DI386 superopt
```

*Note*: `I386`, not `386`.

You will see warnings like:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'foo'
```

because the 20 yearold C code does not diligently include the standard
headers that prototype the standard functions that it calls, but `superopt` will build successfully.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that got my two steps closer. I had to include stdlib.h. But I still get lot's of errors. like missing terminating string " character. I think it doesn't understand \ as a next line.

Comment: @DanyBittel Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm not sure if you consider your question answered but if you do, the way to say Thanks is to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer by ticking the adjacent checkmark.